# Error in compiling PoweR package in R studio

Tags: compilation, package

I am using last version of Rtools(4.3) and Rstudio as for aug-15-2023. I receive an error when compiling the PoweR package . Please see below

```
* installing *source* package 'PoweR' ...
** package 'PoweR' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.2.0'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 12.2.0'
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  - 
I'C:/Users/ilean/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/Rcpp/include' - 
I'C:/Users/ilean/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/RcppArmadillo/include'   
-I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  
-O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign 
-c PoweR_init.c -o PoweR_init.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  - 
I'C:/Users/ilean/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/Rcpp/include' - 
I'C:/Users/ilean/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/RcppArmadillo/include'   
-I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"    
 -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c calcpuiss.cpp -o calcpuiss.o
In file included from laws-stats/def-laws-stats.cpp:78,
                 from calcpuiss.cpp:14:
laws-stats/stats/stat16.cpp: In function 'double mc_C_d(double*, int, double*, int*)':
laws-stats/stats/stat16.cpp:196:12: warning: 'medc' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  196 |     double medc; // "the" result
      |            ^~~~
g++ -std=gnu++17 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PoweR.dll tmp.def PoweR_init.o calcpuiss.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack - 
LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath - 
LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 - 
LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: calcpuiss.o:calcpuiss.cpp:(.text+0x35644): undefined reference to `call_R'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'PoweR'
```

How can I solve this?

I tried to modify, update/add remove,etc mingw32 and or 64 and nothing.
One should note also that PoweR was moved to archive....

Thank you in advance